# Modify list length within for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I know it's not recommended to change a list while iterating over it, but I'm curious as to why the two different codes below give different results:

```
numbers = [1,2]
for i in numbers :
    if len(numbers)<3:
        numbers.append(3)
    print(i)
```

and

```
numbers = [1,2]
for i in numbers :
    if len(numbers)<3:
        numbers = [1,2,3]
    print(i)
```

The first code outputs 1,2,3 and the seconde code outputs only 1,2.

I would expect both code to behave exactly the same as in both cases I'm modifying the content of the list I'm ranging over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing `numbers = [1, 2, 3]`, you did not change the content of the pre-existing list `numbers` to `[1, 2, 3]`, you assigned `[1, 2, 3]` to a new variable.

You need to write `numbers[:] = [1, 2, 3]` to keep the old list alive and change its content. That will print `1, 2, 3` as you expect.